# CSS not working when running my page in web browser

Tags: html, css

This is my html coding. When I run the webpage in firefox there is no color or formating at all it is just the info I entered. I tried typing the code differently and still does not work. I went into developer in firefox and the css does not show up, when I add it the webpage is formatted. How do I fix this so I do not need to go into developer to add the css everytime?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Penn State Health St. Joseph Radiology Employee Reference</title>
        <!-- Author: Brie Rennig -->
        <!-- Date: 08/24/2016 -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rem.css">
    </head> 
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>
    Penn State Health St. Joseph Radiology Employee Reference
</h1>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="rem_index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Workflow.html">Workflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="Scrubs.html">Uniforms</a></li>
        <li><a href="Protocols.html">Protocols</a></li>
        <li><a href="PACS.html">PACS</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resources.html">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="Students.html">Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="About_Us.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    <main>
        <center>
            <img src="ps_health.jpg" id="ps_health">
        </center>
        <br>
        <div id="Statement_Health">
        <center>    
            <h2>
            Mission Statement
            </h2>
            <!-- This text is emphasised as it is the mission statement for Penn State Health -->
            <em>
            The Mission of St. Joseph's is to nurture the healing ministry of the Church, supported by education and research. <br/>
            Fidelity to the Gospel urges us to emphasize human dignity and social justice as we create healthier communities. <br/>
            <br/>
            </em>
        </center>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="Prayer">
            <h3>
            Radiologic Technologist Prayer
            </h3>
            <em>
            Almighty and merciful Lord, <br/>
            I thank thee for giving me this day <br/>
            That I may be able to serve my brethren.<br/>
            <br/>

            Thou give me a keen of mind, <br/>
            To be able to formulate appropriate factor <br/>
            Just enough kVp to penetrate <br/>
            And mAs for density <br/>
            To produce a good quality radiograph. <br/>
            <br/>

            Grant that I may also possess <br/>
            A hand with a tender touch <br/> 
            That I may not intensify the suffering <br/>
            as I position the patient.. <br/>
            <br/>

            Lastly Lord, let me wear a sweet smile, <br/>
            And speak soft and pleasant words <br/>
            which may sooth the afflicted <br/>
            And that they may have confidence in me. <br/>
            <br/>

            For the honor and glory of Thy kingdom <br/>
            Amen. <br/>
            <br/>
            </em>
        </div>

    <footer>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="rem_index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Workflow.html">Workflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="Scrubs.html">Uniforms</a></li>
        <li><a href="Protocols.html">Protocols</a></li>
        <li><a href="PACS.html">PACS</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resources.html">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="Students.html">Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="About_Us.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />

<p> <font face="algerian"> <font color= "#CCCCFF"> Posted by: Brianna Rennig </font> </p> </font>
<p> <font color= "#CCCCFF"> Contact Information: <a href="mailto:btr130@psu.edu">btr130@psu.edu</>.</font> </p>
<a href="http://www.thefutureofhealthcare.org/"> Penn State Health St. Joseph  </a> 
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS

```
body {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5, #0045cc);
         }

    #ps_health
        {

        }
    #ballon_quote
        {
            border:5px;
            border-style:ridge;
            border-color:dark-blue;
            width:60%;
            height:50%;
        }

    #sms_MobileOnly
        {
            display: none;
        }   

    #Statement_Health 
        {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width:90%;
            border: 2px solid; black;
            background-color: #CCCCFF;
        }
    #Prayer
        {
            margin-left: 25%;
            margin-right: auto;
            width:50%;
            border: 2px solid; black;
            background-color: #CCCCFF;
            text-align: center;
        }

    footer ul
        {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

    footer li
        {
            display: inline;
        }

    footer a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

    nav ul
        {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    nav a 
        { 
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    #wrapper 
        { 
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: #EAEAEA; 
        }
    header 
        { 
            background-color: #CCCCFF; 
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto; 
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            text-align: center;
        }
    main 
        { 
            margin-left: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color:  #FFFFFF; 
            font-family: Times New Roman ;
        }
    footer 
        { 
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #CCCCFF; 
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto; 
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    nav
        {
            float: left;
            width: 250px;
        }
```

Comment: At a guess, it isn't finding the file "rem.css".  Does it list it in sources?

Comment: Syntax error in CSS `#ballon_quote` `height:50%;"`

Comment: where would I go to see if it is listed in sources?

Also I just removed that section from the CSS I do opted not to have that on the site

Comment: Dan is right.  There is a stray speech mark there.  It should be removed.

Comment: @Dan Wilson has suggested a solution to your problem, have you checked it out?

Comment: I removed #ballon_quote height:50%;"  from the CSS and it is still not working

Comment: With the HTML page open, go to View Source (Ctrl + U) and find the `<link>` tag. It should be a clickable link and clicking on it should open the CSS source. If not, then make sure that rem.css is in the same directory as your HTML page.

Comment: I finally got it working now. Thank you guys so much for your help